# Two SUMs from same SQL query

Tags: php, sql, sorting, sum

I have this query:

```
SELECT hour, SUM(field1+field2+field3) as product_total  
FROM db.dbf 
WHERE (product_ID BETWEEN 999 AND 9999) AND day IN ($date1,$date2) 
GROUP BY hour
```

The query works and produces the total products with the ID between 999 and 9999.
Results look like this:

```
hour     total_products
12:00    503
12:15    645
12:30    324
12:45    1268
```

I need to separate some products_ID from the total SUM. Therefor I have another query:

```
SELECT hour, SUM(field1+field2+field3) as separated_total  
FROM db.dbf 
WHERE (product_ID BETWEEN 999 AND 1200 OR product_ID BETWEEN 6000 AND 7000) 
AND day IN ($date1,$date2) 
GROUP BY hour
```

I want a result like this:

```
hour     total_products   separated_products
12:00    503              63
12:15    645              53
12:30    324              120
12:45    1268             348
```

I want my array to look like this:

```
array("hour" => $row['hour'], "products' => $row['product_total'], "separated_products" => $row['separated_total'])
```

My problem is that I'm working with a huge table and the fact that I'm using two separate queries makes the processing time a little bit too long for my taste.
How can I make this into one, more efficient query? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, simply apply the extra filter.

```
SELECT
  hour,
  SUM(field1+field2+field3) AS total,
  SUM(field1+field2+field3) FILTER (
    WHERE product_ID BETWEEN 999 AND 1200
          OR product_ID BETWEEN 6000 AND 7000) as separated_total
FROM db.dbf 
WHERE day IN ($date1, $date2)
GROUP BY hour
```

For everything else there's the CASE statement.

```
SELECT
  hour,
  SUM(field1+field2+field3) AS total,
  SUM(CASE WHEN product_ID BETWEEN 999 AND 1200
                OR product_ID BETWEEN 6000 AND 7000
           THEN field1+field2+field3
           ELSE 0
      END) AS separated_total
FROM db.dbf 
WHERE day IN ($date1, $date2)
GROUP BY hour
```

Comment: I tried this and got an error: [Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'SUM(field1+field2+field3) FILTER (WHERE product_ID BETWEEN 999 AND 1400 OR product_ID BETWEEN 5999 AND 7000)'.

Comment: Well you didn't exactly specify which RDBMS you're using. First implementation is Postgresql-specific. Second is universal.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using UNION like below but I am not sure how to use GROUP BY here

```
SELECT hour, SUM(field1+field2+field3) as separated_total  
FROM db.dbf 
WHERE (product_ID BETWEEN 999 AND 1200 OR product_ID BETWEEN 6000 AND 7000) 
AND day IN ($date1,$date2) 
UNION 
SELECT hour, SUM(field1+field2+field3) as separated_products  
FROM db.dbf 
WHERE (product_ID BETWEEN 6000 AND 7000) 
AND day IN ($date1,$date2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have two sums based on your criteria as long as your where includes both

```
SelECT hour, SUM(field1+field2+field3) as total1, sum(case when product_id between 6000 and 7000 then field1+field2+field3 else 0 end) total2  
FroM db.dbf 
WheRE (product_ID BETWEEN 999 AND 1200 OR product_ID BETWEEN 6000 AND 7000) 
And day IN ($date1,$date2) 
Group BY hour
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already multiple answers, but I think the simplest is:

```
SELECT hour, SUM(field1 + field2 + field3) as separated_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN product_ID BETWEEN 999 AND 1200 OR
                     product_ID BETWEEN 6000 AND 7000
                THEN field1 + field2 + field3
                ELSE 0
           END) as separated_totl  
FROM db.dbf 
WHERE day IN ($date1, $date2) AND
      product_id BETWEEN 999 AND 9999
GROUP BY hour
ORDER BY hour;  -- in general, you should not assume the ordering of the results
```

This works because your special sum is a subset of the general sum, so the same `WHERE` clause works.  The performance should be essentially the same as your original query.

I would also encourage you to use parameters, rather than munging query strings with things like date constants.